# How to attach User model with two different Models so that the properties of those models can be accessed via current_user

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am building a online quiz app where both teacher and students can login. Teachers can create quizzes and students can run those quizzes. How can I attach both **Teacher** and **Student** model with User model so that properties like **Teacher_Name** or **Student_Class** etc can be accessed via **current_user**?

This is not a problem regarding user role. Because using **flask-security** I can do that pretty easily but providing role means grouping users by their access level but not actually identifying them. I mean if a student logs in I need know who is this particular student represented by the current logged in user. Only then I can store his/her result with his/her record.

Followings are my **sqlalchemy** models...

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'student'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cls = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False, default='V')
    sec = db.Column(db.String(1), nullable=False, default='A')
    roll = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)
    name = db.Column(db.String(24), nullable=False)
    dob = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sex = db.Column(db.Enum(Gender), nullable=False, default=Gender.male)
    results = db.relationship('Result', backref='student', lazy=True)
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint("cls", "roll", name="cls_roll"),)

class Teacher(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(24), nullable=False)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False)

quiz_ques = db.Table('quiz_ques', db.Column('quiz_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quiz.id'), nullable=False),
                     db.Column('mcq_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mcq.id'), nullable=False),
                     db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('quiz_id', 'mcq_id'))


class Quiz(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'quiz'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False)
    marks = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)
    time_limit = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=20)
    questions = db.relationship('MCQ', secondary=quiz_ques, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('quizzes', lazy=True))
    results = db.relationship('Result', backref='quiz', lazy=True)

class MCQ(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mcq'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False)
    topic = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    question = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    answers = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)

class Result(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'result'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    marks_obtained = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    response = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=True)
    stud_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.id'), nullable=False)
    quiz_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quiz.id'), nullable=False)
```

The code should allow me to do something like this -

current_user.student.name = 'John Doe'
or 
current_user.teacher.subject = 'Math'

Comment: With a foreign key in the User model? Could a teacher also be a student or vice versa?

Comment: No a teacher can not be a student. Teacher and Student are 2 different entity here. That means the user may be a student or a teacher but can never be both. That's the problem. I thought about the foreign key. But one thing is that the relationship between user to student or user to teacher should be one to one. Because each student or each teacher can have only one user login. So any idea how to pull it off?

Comment: How about adding boolean flags `is_student` and `is_teacher` to your user model?

Comment: Yes I could do that. But still I have to relate both student and teacher with user. The whole thing is becoming complicated. Is there any alternative to this? I mean this is a standard problem. There should be a standard solution to this kind of problems not some patch work, right?

Comment: What I am really want to know is that can I some way define 2 usermixin class and then somehow modify the user_loader function so that it could take 2 arguments user_id and user_type. Based on user_type the user_id will be used to load the user from the right usermixin class. Is there any i can do that?